# How to create DBA user from oracle APEX 11gR2 XE

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-apex

Please anyone tell me how to create DBA user from ORACLE Application express(http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/apex_admin)?

I installed **Oracle 11gR2 XE** on windows 8.1 PC and I am able to login to Oracle APEX (above link) with username: "ADMIN" and password used during installation. but I can't use same username/password to login to "Oracle SQL Command Line". I am trying to connect with command

```
CONNECT username/password
```

All other solutions suggests a command "CREATE USER....." but I don't know where to write that command without connecting SQL Command line. I am missing a simple step somewhere. please help me.

My question is exactly opposite of this question. [User with dba privs can't login to APEX, but can from SQL*Plus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41548/user-with-dba-privs-cant-login-to-apex-but-can-from-sqlplus/106202#106202)

Where I can login to Oracle APEX web interface and create new workspace, Schemas, Users but I am not able to login to SQL Command line to create Database objects.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40562/creating-an-admin-user-in-oracle

Comment: Sorry, That didn't help me.

SQL> CONNECT /as sysdba 
Error:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: Raj - In order for that to work, you will need to add your WINDOWS OS USER account to the ora_dba group. This allows any user in that group to issue 'sqlplus / as sysdba' or 'connect / as sysdba' without sys credentials. Then you can use sqlplus to create users, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [article from dba-oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031_insufficient_privileges.htm) which talk about this same problem. This might solve the issue you are having.